# How to store an arraylist which has content class (class in project)?

Tags: android

I want to store an `ArrayList<class>` in shared preference. But the error showed up in `editor3.putString("Array", nama);`. I guess the error caused by `putString`. What sould i do?

Should I used another method to storing arraylist ?

```
ArrayList<Class> nama = new ArrayList<Class>(9);
nama.add(dragsandal.class);nama.add(Terimakasih.class);
nama.add(Ludah.class);
nama.add(Permisi.class);
nama.add(Tolong.class);
nama.add(Maaf.class);
SharedPreferences pref3 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Array", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = pref3.edit();
editor3.putString("Array", nama);
editor3.apply();
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Why do you want to store `Class` objects in shared preferences?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice because I dont know another method to save arraylist with class type.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: Why do you need to store `Class` objects at all? This seems strange to me since classes are available directly and immediately in Java code without the need to store them as external data. Are you sure you don't want to share **instances** of these classes instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`putStringSet(Set<String>)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) to store sets (Lists with unique elements). `SharedPreferences` do not provide a method to store lists directly.

You can easily convert your list to a set using e.g. `new HashSet<String>(yourList);`

If you need to store a list, you can serialize your list to a `String`, e.g. by using `Gson` and storing the json value. Then `putString(json)` would be correct.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your reply. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @JatiDyah feel free to accept this post if it answered your question

Answer (score 0):

First I don't think there is a way to store lists in Shared preferences. Second it is not a good idea. In your case,I would consider using Sqlite database. It would make things easier.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your reply. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store a Class type object in SharedPreferences.  Also you can't store Lists.  If you really need to, you can store the full name of the class object as a String.  Then when you read the value back you, you can use Class.forName() to convert that string back to a class.  It seems weird, but you can do it.

You could try this to save and restore a set of class names:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.put(Terimakasih.class.getName());
set.put(Ludah.class.getName());
set.put(Permisi.class.getName());
set.put(Tolong.class.getName());
set.put(Maaf.class.getName());
SharedPreferences pref3 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("set", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = pref3.edit();
editor3.putStringSet("set", set);
editor3.apply();

Set<String> strings = pref3.getStringSet("set", Collections.emptySet());
Set<Class> classes = new HashSet<Class>();
for (String s : strings) {
    classes.put(Class.forName(s));
}
```

Comment: I've tried and the error is 'error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown'. The error caised by the code in 'classes.put(Class.forName(s));' , can you solve it ?

Comment: Yes, you have to catch that exception and decide what you want to do with it if the class isn't found. If you're certain that the class will always be found, then you still have to catch the exception, but you don't have to do anything with it.

Comment: Thankyou so much. It helps me alot. I just add more line to solved it.   'for (String s : strings) {
            try{
                classes.add(Class.forName(s));
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException ignore){
            }
        }'

Comment: Great, glad it helped!  If the solution solves the problem, please accept it here.

Comment: I have a problem. I remove one of item in 'set'. Thus, the 'set' size is 5. But when I move to the activity again, the 'set' not change. The 'set' size is back with 6. It seems because 'getStringSet()'. Can u solve it ? @Doug Stevenson

Comment: Did you write the set back to the SharedPreference after removing an item from it?  Changes to your collection won't automatically write through to a SharedPreference.  You have to write the SharedPreference for every change.